# Finding values for $n$ so that $a^n+b>n^2$

Tags: proof-verification

If we have $a>1$ and $a,b \in R$, what values of $n$ (which will probably be relating to $a$ and $b$) will make this inequality true?

$a^n+b>n^2$

I HAD a theory that it's related to $n=max$ {${a+|b|,\frac{|b|}{a-1}}$} works but I'm having trouble proving it.

Comment: Try $a=1.5, b=0$

Comment: Shoot you're right, that disproves my idea. Do you have any clue how to solve this algebraically?

Comment: What is $n$? An integer? A positive integer? Any real number? Note: If $b>-1$ and $n=0$ the equation is also satisfied.

Comment: IMO you have to solve it numerically. For large $n$ you know than $a^n$ grows

Comment: If this is a rehashing of your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2946506/proving-an-b-n2-for-every-n-n-for-some-natural-number-n) note that in your original question we don't care at all about finding the smallest value of $n$ making that true, we only cared about finding at least one $n$ for which it is true (*and is true for all other values of $n$ above it*), or more accurately, proving that such an $n$ exists (*and not even bother explicitly finding it*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a = 1 + t$, $$(1+t)^n \ge 1 + n t +  {n \choose 2} t^2 + {n \choose 3} t^3 $$
so it is sufficient to have $n > -b/t$ and ${n \choose 3}/n^2 > 1/t^3$.  Note that
$$ {n \choose 3}/n^2 = \frac{n}{6} - \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3n}$$
so  it is enough that 
$$n > \max\left(\frac{-b}{t}, 3 + \frac{6}{t^3} \right)$$.

Comment: That all looks good, I'm just wondering how you got that $n>-b/t$

Comment: This makes $nt + b > 0$.

Comment: Hi there, sorry I'm still struggling seeing how you came up with that. Could you explain a little more why it is sufficient to have $n>−b/t$ and $n \choose 3$ $/n^2>1/t^3$?

Comment: $a^n + b = (1+t)^n + b >  (n t + b)+ {n \choose 3} t^3  > 0 + n^2$.